# how to find all pics in a directory and its subdirectories and run a command on them

Tags: find, recursive, imagemagick, exif, mogrify

how to find all images in a directory and its sub-directories, with types `gif, jpg, jpeg, png, ico`, and run `mogrify -strip your_filename.jpg` on them?

Can the command `mogrify -strip` corrupt an image?

Also can the command `mogrify -strip` be run on a gif file?

Comment: (1) Please take our short [tour] to see how the site is designed to work. One question per post please. (2) "Can the command `mogrify -strip` be run on a gif file?" – What keeps you from trying?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two parts in your question, the first one, you can run any command on files using something like this:

```
find /path "*.gif" -exec cmd {} \;
```

It's important to have a single space after {}.

as for the **mogrify**, it's safer to take a look at the documentation and run some tests.

[Link to man mogrify](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mogrify)

Comment: thanks. for some reason it wouldn't run when I did something similar. now that I look at it it was cause I tried to do two things with && and for that I probably should have used bash -c